# Why does Razor page (OnX) handler get invoked twice in debug/visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm writing a razor site and while trying to debug something else I noticed that the page handler for any page in my project appears to be invoked twice. Does not happen in the published production version.

e.g.:

Any page in the project's model, and any handler type (get/post):

```
    public void OnGet()
    {
        _logger.LogTrace("Main index page get");
    }
```

The log records:

```
2019-03-11 10:11:55.9120||TRACE|*****.Pages.IndexModel|Main index page get |url: https://localhost/|action: 
2019-03-11 10:11:56.7514||TRACE|*****.Pages.IndexModel|Main index page get |url: https://localhost/|action:
```

And with a breakpoint it hits the breakpoint twice, the browser dev tools network log shows one request. All browsers provoke the same behavior.

I cannot for the life of me work out why the handlers are being hit twice! Needless to say that this is complicating debugging a new feature.

Any ideas?

PS: I restarted VS on my dev workstation, and restarted it, searched around in case there were multiple processes listening anything else vaguely related I could think of - no result.

Comment: Just testing now, it appears to be a custom middleware causing the problem - or at least an edit to it since production last was published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with any of the framework. My custom middleware failed to abort processing the pipeline under a specific condition. I edited the middleware to abort its processing if we're in development environment (because it was annoying) but I failed.

Essentially I said:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(...)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
         // Do stuff to make the rest of the work of this MW irrelevant
         await _next(context);
    }

    // Rest of middleware including another await _next(context)
}
```

Clearly, this is a stupid mistake. Lesson for me/all: make sure your middleware is rock solid.